# Append multiple pandas data frames at once

Tags: python, pandas, append

I am trying to find some way of appending multiple pandas data frames at once rather than appending them one by one using

```
df.append(df)
```

Let us say there are 5 pandas data frames `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`, `t5`. How do I append them at once? Something equivalent of

```
df = rbind(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5)
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Have you simply tried using a list as argument of append? Or am I missing anything?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = np.asarray(pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = df1.copy()
df3 = df1.copy()
df = df1.append([df2, df3])

print df
```

Comment: And a symmetric solution: `pd.DataFrame().append([df1,df2, df3])`.

Comment: From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html): "Parameters: other: DataFrame or Series/dict-like object, __or list of these__" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 129):

I think you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print pd.concat([t1, t2, t3, t4, t5])
```

Maybe you can `ignore_index`:

```
print pd.concat([t1, t2, t3, t4, t5], ignore_index=True)
```

More info in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects).

Comment: if you want them merged by some value, lets say by that in the first column, you can also do: `pd.concat([t1, t2, t3, t4, t5], axis=1)`

Comment: pd.concat([t1, t2, t3, t4, t5],  axis=0, ignore_index=True)

Answer (score 5):

if the **columns each data frame is different** you can add for to append :

```
#list dataframe you want to append
frame = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]

#new dataframe to store append result
myDataFrame = pd.DataFrame()

for df in frame:
    myDataFrame = myDataFrame.append(df)
```

make sure append success by checking the myDataFrame lenght with :

```
len(myDataFrame)
```

if all columns in the data frame is the same or the columns difference each data frame will not be a concern as long as the number of columns of each data frame is the same you can use `pd.concat(dataframe)` as mention by jezrael.

for more info about append and concat, please click link below :
[Merge, join, concatenate and compare in Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have one main Excel file in which we have 3 sub-sheets named by `p1`,`p2` & `p3`

We can read all the sheets together as follows:

```
d = pd.read_excel('p1.xlsx',sheet_name=['p1','p2','p3'])
```

Now to combine all sheets in one data frame, we can use the following:

```
df=pd.concat(d[frame] for frame in d.keys())
```