# Can't we append a large number of time series together?

Tags: python, dataframe, append

I am facing silly error with my append operation: suppose I have about 600 separate dataframes of shape (6,10) and I want to concatenate them in one big dataframe with append() in a for loop. 
Doing this for the first 100 df works just fine but it generates the following error once I reach 300 dataframes:

"Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

here is the code snippet:

```
for i in range(400):
## Do some processing
temp =  pd.concat([temp,ts.iloc[:,1]], axis=1)
df_pred_ult = df_pred_ult.append(temp)
```

So , my question, doesn't append() work well for a huge number of df? Is there a better way to do so...

Comment: What about `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, dfn], ignore_index=True)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36526282/2901002)

Comment: df_pred_ult = pd.concat([df_pred_ult,temp], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

Comment: No duplicate rows , I have already checked...

Comment: Is possible create list of all dataframes and then use `concat` ?