# append multiple(+100) pandas data frames to master dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I found this post: [append multiple pandas data frames at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526282/append-multiple-pandas-data-frames-at-once)

I understand how this work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = np.asarray(pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = df1.copy()
df3 = df1.copy()
df = df1.append([df2, df3])

print df
```

But how do I do it if I have +100 dataframes to append to df1?

df2, df3....df99,df100

I do have a list that has all of my dataframes:

list1 = [df1, df2,..., df100]

obs. My dataframes do not have the same columns.

For example:

```
print(list1[1]):

           email   spot      speed  d1   d2
0  tom@gmail.com  copenhagen  5     West North 


print(list[2]):

              email    spot speed    d1    d2    d3
 0  sasha@gmail.com    Malmo   17   South South North
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: So is problem use `df = pd.concat(list1)` ? If some columns are not in some child dataframes, then are created `NaN`s values.

Comment: @jezrael yes. That worked. Thanks! must have overseen that possibility some how. /T

Comment: Yes, it is second answer :)