# how to append data from different data frame in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have about 20 data frames and all data frames are having same columns and I would like to add data into the empty data frame but when I use my code

interested_freq

```
     UPC    CPC   freq
0   136.0   B64G    2
1   136.0   H01L    1
2   136.0   H02S    1
3   244.0   B64G    1
4   244.0   H02S    1
5   257.0   B64G    1
6   257.0   H01L    1
7   312.0   B64G    1
8   312.0   H02S    1

    list_of_lists = []
    max_freq = df_interested_freq[df_interested_freq['freq'] == df_interested_freq['freq'].max()]
    for row, cols in max_freq.iterrows():
        interested_freq = df_interested_freq[df_interested_freq['freq'] != 1]
        interested_freq 
        list_of_lists.append(interested_freq)

    list_of_lists
```

for append the first data frame, and then change the name in that code for hoping that it will append more data

```
list_of_lists = []
    for row, cols in max_freq.iterrows():
        interested_freq_1 = df_interested_freq_1[df_interested_freq_1['freq'] != 1]
        interested_freq_1 
        list_of_lists.append(interested_freq_1)

    list_of_lists
```

but the first data is disappeared and show only the recent appended data. do I have done something wrong?

Comment: do all the dataframes have same columns ?

Comment: yes, all data frames are having same columns

Comment: how about `pd.concat(df_lists)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append multiple pandas data frames at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526282/append-multiple-pandas-data-frames-at-once)

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate, you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526282/append-multiple-pandas-data-frames-at-once

Answer (score 1):

One way to Create a new DataFrame from existing DataFrame is use to `df.copy()`:
[Here is Detailed documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

The `df.copy()` is very much relevant here because changing the subset of data within new dataframe will change the initial DataFrame So, you have fair chances of losing your actual dataFrame thus you need it.

**Suppose Example DataFrame is** `df1` :

```
>>> df1
   col1  col2
1    11    12
2    21    22
```

**Solution** , you can use df.copy method as follows which will inherit the data along.

```
>>> df2 = df1.copy()
>>> df2
   col1  col2
1    11    12
2    21    22
```

In case you need to new dataframe(`df2`) to be created  as like `df1` but don't want the values to inserted across the DF then you have option to use `reindex_like()` method.

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df1)
# df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan,columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)
>>> df2
   col1  col2
1   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use append here? It’s not a list. Once you have the first dataframe (called d1 for example), try:

```
new_df = df1
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df2])
```

You can do the same thing for all 20 dataframes.