# Add multiple csv files into one csv file got error with NaN using panda

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Here I have three csv files with same headers. I want to merge that three csv files into one csv file with same headers.
here is my three csv file. I want to write it using panda python with column names. I saw so many solutions but it didn't work for me. Can anyone helps me to solve this problem?

csv 1

[image]

csv2

[image]

csv 3

[image]

output be like:

[image]

After trying the codes that you all suggest me and it gives me this without no values in some columns, no header name.

[image]

After trying your code (@Benji) it gave me an output with NaN values:
[image]

error:
[image]

dataframe after change the code

[image]

Comment: Could you specify how your output is going to look like? Merging in order by time?  or just merging?

Comment: @benji I upload the image of the output. You can see that csv 1,csv2,csv3 files data come in together

Comment: can you us how you did read a `.csv` file?

Comment: @benji I tried your code, but it gave output with NaN values.

Comment: I read my csv file using panda. (data1 = pd.read_csv('temp1.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('temp2.csv')
data3 = pd.read_csv('temp3.csv')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append multiple pandas data frames at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526282/append-multiple-pandas-data-frames-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by “merge” you mean union. Here is how to do that

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=str) for filename in ["f1.csv", "f2.csv", "f3.csv"]],
    axis=0,
).to_csv("union.csv")
```

Comment: when I tried your code it gives me this no header name , no values in some column . I pasted the image of that. Can you look at that?

Comment: Try adding `header = 0` before `dtype=str` in the `pd.read_csv` part

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('f1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('f2.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('f3.csv')

frames = [df1, df2, df3]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: when I tried your code it gives me this but without error (FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=True'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass sort=False) Can you explain this please?

Answer (score 0):

There's might be a problem when you read `.csv` file 
Try to read like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv', header = 0, names=['date', 'time', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv', header = 0, names=['date', 'time', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
df3 = pd.read_csv('3.csv', header = 0, names=['date', 'time', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3'])    
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 0)
df = df.sort_values('time').reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: yes that is true. I read my csv file wrongly. After change it and using your code it gave me this error ( '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str') I pasted the image of the error.Can you tell me why is it coming like that?

Comment: @awa Can you print out a datafram after reading? I guess that time column might contain both str and float which it's supposed to be only float.

Comment: Sure I paste the image of that. You may can look at it.

Comment: @awa Please upload a sample of your .csv file (not the whole data, just sample of it). It would be a lot easier for me to help you.

Comment: Sure I did it and I pasted it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and solved it like this:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i) for i in csv_files])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The important line is the `df.reset_index(drop=True`. That's what joins the columns.

Comment: I had a bunch of csv files all following a particular format, so I read them with something like this: 
`csv_files = ['data_america_2018_03_0' + str(i) for i in range(1,7)]`

Comment: Okay I will try . Thank you