# How to Create Multiple Data Frames in For Loop

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list of names (I changed them to letters) that correspond with values in a data frame column.

```
names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
```

I am trying to create a separate data frame for each name containing that name's associated QTY grouped by part number.

```
for x in names:
    name_data = data[data['Name']== x]
    name_dict = name_data.groupby(['Part No.']).Quantity.sum().to_dict()
    df1= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(name_dict, orient = 'index',columns = ['QTY'])
```

As you can see from the code each time it loops it writes the new loop data over the previous loop's data in df1. How to I iterate a new data frame name each time it loops, so that I end of with 8 separate data frames?

Comment: Maybe you could append instead of concat them like this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526282/append-multiple-pandas-data-frames-at-once and just append each dataframe after each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

You could save the dataframes to a `list`:

```
list_of_dfs = list()

for x in names:
    df = data[data['Name'].eq(x)].groupby('Part No.')['Quantity'].sum().rename("QTY").to_frame()
    list_of_dfs.append(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I gave it a shot, but had a few problems. I was hoping to put the data in data frames so that I could add more columns of information to the data as I go. Can I do this once it is a list, or can I then convert the QTY data in the list back to data frames?

Comment: This is a list of dataframes. So if you do `list_of_dfs[0]`, that would give you  a DataFrame. You can do whatever you need with that.